# RealmSwift error: "RLMException, reason: Collection was mutated while being enumerated."

Tags: swift, nspredicate, enumeration, realm

I am getting the following error:
"RLMException, reason: Collection was mutated while being enumerated."

I get the error when I try to do this:

```
let realm = Realm()

let words = realm.objects(Word).filter("ANY collectedSentences.characterCount > 0")

realm.write {
    for word in words {
        word.collectedSentences.removeAll()
    }
}
```

I don't get that error If instead I do this:

```
let realm = Realm()
let words = realm.objects(Word)

realm.write {
    for word in words {
        word.collectedSentences.removeAll()
    }
}
```

How can I do something like the first example so the program doesn't have to go through all the words?

Comment: What kind of object is collectedSentences? It's possible that the predicate query is being automatically re-triggered when you delete the object while already in a loop.

Comment: collectedSentences is a List<Sentence>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the clarification. Since `collectedSentences` is a Realm List object, then deleting it would invalidate the results of the original query, which is what's causing the exception.

One way to get around this (Which I've used in my own app before) is to make a static copy of the results of the query as an array (Sadly, this is a manual process where you must loop through the results object, and add each one to the array). You can can then loop through that array and delete all of the elements in there without triggering a mutation exception.